# How i can Find Difference between two Associative arrays having one common Key

Tags: php, arrays, php-7.2

I am Working in Magento 2.3  i have two arrays

**First Array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => /l/u/luma-foam-roller.jpg
            [image_id] => luma-foam-roller.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => /l/u/luma-yoga-strap-set.jpg
            [image_id] => luma-yoga-strap-set.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => /m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg
            [image_id] => mb04-black-0.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => /l/u/luma-stability-ball-pink.jpg
            [image_id] => luma-stability-ball-pink.jpg
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => /m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg
            [image_id] => mb01-blue-0.jpg
        )
}
```

**Second Array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => /m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => /m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => /m/b/mb04-black-0_alt1.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => /m/b/mb03-black-0.jpg
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => /m/b/mb03-black-0_alt1.jpg
        )
}
```

i want to find difference on the basis of name 
Expected Result for me is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => /l/u/luma-foam-roller.jpg
            [image_id] => luma-foam-roller.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => /l/u/luma-yoga-strap-set.jpg
            [image_id] => luma-yoga-strap-set.jpg
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => /l/u/luma-stability-ball-pink.jpg
            [image_id] => luma-stability-ball-pink.jpg
        )

}
```

i tried Following Functions But Non of them are working for me

- array_diff()
- array_diff_assoc()
- array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);

but not getting any success

Comment: Please could you correct the spelling mistakes in the title @WaqarAli .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any one liner function that does this automatically at this time, but one straightforward way is just to use a loop.

```
$names = array_column($second, 'name');
$diff = array();
foreach ($first as $k => $values) {
    if (!in_array($values['name'], $names)) {
        $diff[$k] = $values;
    }
}
// print_r($diff);
```

Basically you just get all the names first (via `array_column`) and make em flat, so that you can utilize `in_array` and make your search and comparison.

Then, it's just a humble `foreach` and `if` at that point. This example creates a new copy of the difference. If you prefer not to create another copy, you can just `unset()` the first array and reverse the condition, leaving only the difference on the original.

Answer (score 1):

[array_udiff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) can help:

```
function compare_by_name($a, $b) {
    $nameA = isset($a['name']) ? $a['name'] : '';
    $nameB = isset($b['name']) ? $b['name'] : '';

    return strcmp($nameA, $nameB);
}

print_r(array_udiff($arr1, $arr2, 'compare_by_name'));
```

Comment: nice, or just simply `return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);`